# Magento -> Rerewrite model

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the model:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
```

But I use the add-on "Payone" which already overrides it:

```
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <quote_address>Payone_Core_Model_Sales_Quote_Address</quote_address>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
```

I tried:

```
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_quote_address>Mycomp_Mymod_Model_Quote_Address</sales_quote_address>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
```

But this doesn't work. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless my memory escapes me, you'll want to make your module "dependent" on their module so that your rewrite comes last and takes effect. You do this by adding the following to your `app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml` file within the  node:

```
<depends>
     <Their_Module />
</depends>
```

Once you do that, have your class extend theirs:

```
class My_Module_Model_Quote_Address extends Payone_Core_Model_Sales_Quote_Address
```

If you can do what you need using an event observer, then do that instead. But if you need the rewrite, the above will get you where you need to be.

Comment: Although this is nice indeed, I am not totally content with this solution as it makes it even harder to disable modules. It might still be the easiest option though for now.

Comment: +1 as it is the best solution... This is a PHP problem (lack of multiple inheritance) rather than a Magento problem - though it does suffer from it.

Comment: @Lucasmus I agree, it's not necessarily the best way to have to handle these sort of issues due the reasons you mentioned, observers/hooks/multiple-inheritance would be better. As Daniel said, it is the result of PHP being a single-inheritance language. PHP 5.4 will be adding support for [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), but I doubt Magento will be re-architected to use them (and mandate the use of PHP 5.4) any time soon. So for now we are stuck with using the abilities of the language and platform the modules are built for. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use observer insted of your rewrite (believe me, you can make a lot of modifications without rewrites. `<model>_load_after`, `<model>_save_before`, `<model>_save_after`, `<model>_load_after` are very powerfull).

But if you still need to make rewrite you can add `depends` node to your module (to make sure it will be loaded after Payone) and rewrite Payone_Core_Model_Sales_Quote_Address instead of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address

There is one more way to solve this problem: to merge all changes in your class and remove previous rewrite. But this way add mess to the whole system and affects the integrity of modularity.

Answer (score 1):

Well... its missing from david alger's answer... the above answer, is a much more sound architectural approach, use Object Composition in an event observer to work with the object if you can avoid extending.

Let me explain why it isn't working for you:

When system configuration is loaded from all modules, it is loaded in whatever order the .xml files are consumed. When a rewrite is issued, Magento configuration makes a record at the same level as the config xml hierarchy which would reference that class `<class>`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Addess`</class>`

Whenever Magento loads a class, it checks @ that hierarchy level for a `<rewrite>`Payone_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`</rewrite>` node, loads that if it exists, or the class node if it doesn't exist.

By putting the `<depends><Thier_Module></depends>` node, your rewrite is loading last when configuration loads, and replacing their rewrite at this node level.

***...The problem with not understanding...***

...the underlying functionality that causes your problem is that future module introduction could rewrite your module and you're going to be scratching your head again... what happens if you introduce another module that rewrites the same class?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to somehow combine these files into one file and use that file, because Magento doesn't support multiple overwrites for the same file by default.

Aitoc, a Magento extension developer, ships a custom rewrite extension with their modules which seems to handle this, moving multiple overwrites automatically into one if it detects this. I've not tested it yet, but maybe it can help you out.

Comment: The AITOC module's rewrite system is a piece of junk which I would not touch with a ten foot pole. It causes more trouble than it's worth.